# Conditional joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm new in making SQL requests and get confused by joining multiply tables. Here is my problem.
DB engine is Microsoft SQL Server.
I have four following tables with their columns:

```
     document(doc_id, doc_name, ref_type1, ref_type2, etc)
     document_references(doc_id, ref_type, ref_id)
     reference_type1 (ref_id, ref_value)
     reference_type2 (ref_id, ref_value)
```

So when document.ref_type1 field is filled a string to document_references is added.

I need to make some kind of report containig following:

```
    doc_name, etc, reference_type1.ref_value, reference_type2.ref_value
```

That means I need to join reference_type1 and reference_type2 tables to document table.
I'm trying this

```
    document left outer join document_references as refs1
             on (document.doc_id = document_references. doc_id and refs.ref_type = type1)
   refs1  left outer join reference_type1 on
   refs.ref_value = reference_type1.ref_id 
     document left outer join document_references as refs2
             on (document.doc_id = document_references. doc_id and refs2.ref_type = type2)
    refs  left outer join reference_type2 on
   refs.ref_value = reference_type2.ref_id
```

And my output contains all needed fields and works surprisingly OK, but there is a problem. If reference_type2 missing some values the whole string with doc_name, etc and reference_type1.ref_value is not displayed. I guess the same is about reference_type1, but it's table seems to have no null values. What do I do to null values be displayed in result table instead of missing the whole strings?
Thank you in advance!

P.s. my request looks like

```
    SELECT  document.Name   
    --etc   
    , reference_type1.ref_value
    , reference_type2.ref_value
    FROM document 
    LEFT OUTER join document_references as docRefs1
            on document.doc_id = docRefs1.doc_id
             JOIN reference_type1
                ON docRefs1.ref_id = reference_type1.ref_id

    LEFT OUTER join document_references as docRefs2
            on document.doc_id = docRefs2.doc_id
             JOIN reference_type2
                ON docRefs2.ref_id = reference_type2.ref_id
```

The problem is that if document.ref_type is not filled the string is not displayed in result. How can I make it to be displayed with null values?

Comment: What's your whole select statement? Separate your joins by newlines and post your while SQL statement so we can help. Left joins should not exclude results that are in the right hand (source) table, but if you have null checks later, or Dependant inner joins the result would essentially be the same as using an inner join. Post the SQL and maybe we can help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional JOIN Statement SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518526/conditional-join-statement-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

if you specify your join condition as ref_type = type1 you will get an error saying that the column type1 doesnt exist. I have assumed that ref_type is varchar and that the values specified in your query are the values in the document_references table.

```
select 
    d.doc_name, 
    --etc, 
    r1.ref_value, 
    r2.ref_value
from 
    document d
    inner join document_references dr
        on dr.doc_id = d.doc_id
    left outer join reference_type1 r1
        on r1.ref_id = dr.ref_id
        and dr.ref_type = 'type1' 
    left outer join reference_type2 r2
        on r2.ref_id = dr.ref_id
        and dr.ref_type = 'type2'
```

Thanks for putting helpful tags against your answer these (esp DB engine) help us to help you. However when you say the query you posted is working, I don't see how it possibly could be and it actually confused me. Luckily the rest of your question made sense. Im just saying you will get better responses more quickly if you be as clear as possible. If you need me to clear anything up for you or you need further help, let me know.

Comment: I've added a request text and specified tables' structure.

Comment: I have made the joins to the reference_type tables left joins so that the document records are returned but when there is no match for reference type the ref values will be null.