# join one table if condition met otherwise from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to know the SQL query for following condition

I have three tables, `Table 1` from which I want to get data, second is `Table1Mapping` and third is `master` table.

I want to get data from `Table1Mapping` if related data exists otherwise from `master` table and `Table 1`.

`Table 1` will be common.

For example:

Table 1:

```
ID    Name
1     ABC
```

Table1Mapping:

```
Table1ID    Country    Code
1           US         958
2           IND        89
```

master

```
Country     Code
UK          87
US          56
IND         45
```

User can select multiple countries. If he selects US and IND then US Code should be get from `Table1Mapping` and IND should be from `master` as there is no data for Id 1 and US.

Code may be different in both tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional JOIN Statement SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518526/conditional-join-statement-sql-server)

Comment: I think he might be checking on attribute names rather than a value in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide us your schema so i created fantasy data to show how this can look like.

Description:
use 2 LEFT JOINS in Combination with COALESCE, which will give you the first element that is not null.

```
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE
(
    id INT
)

DECLARE @tabMapping TABLE
(
    id INT,
    anycol VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @tabMaster TABLE
(
    id INT,
    anycol VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tab1 (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
INSERT INTO @tabMapping (id,anycol) VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')
INSERT INTO @tabMaster (id,anycol) VALUES (3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e')

SELECT  t1.id,
        COALESCE(map.anycol,mas.anycol,'no data for this id')
FROM    @tab1 t1
        LEFT JOIN @tabMapping map ON t1.id = map.id
        LEFT JOIN @tabMaster mas ON t1.id = mas.id
```

what you should care about: what if data are in mapping and master? what if data are not in mapping nor master! (in my example if nothing is found in mapping and master a default value ("no data for this id") is shown. if data exist in both tables the value will come from the mapping table as it's the first argument in coalesce()...

Comment: @reaanb: Shot in the dark too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables to your Table1 and play a bit with the conditions

Small example based on your description:

```
select
 *
from table1 t1
left join Table1Mapping tm on
    t1.id = tm.id
left join Mastertable mt on
    tm.id is null and
    t1.id = mt.id
```

Comment: Or maybe a union of two queries one with WHERE NOT EXISTS() and the other using WHERE EXISTS()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your schema looks like (in particular how the tables are related), so this is just a shot in the dark:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table1Mapping m ON t.ID = m.Table1_ID
INNER JOIN Master s ON COALESCE(m.Master_ID, t.Master_ID) = s.Master_ID
```

Comment: Sadly much is a shot in the dark

Answer (score 0):

How about LEFT JOIN to both tables and use COALESCE?

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.SomeColumn,mt.SomeColumn) AS SomeColumn
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1Mapping m ON t1.PK=m.FK
LEFT JOIN MasterTable mt ON t1.PK=mt.FK
```

A LEFT JOIN will produce NULL values when there is no matching row.
A COALESCE will return the first non-NULL value in its list of arguments.

So the effect will be that if a non-NULL value was found in Table1Mapping, it will be returned, otherwise the value from MasterTable will be returned.