# SQL JOIN Depending on Condition

Tags: php, mysql

My question pertains to joining data based on a specific condition.

For example, in table A there is a column known as user_type.  If user_type is 1, I want to do an INNER JOIN from table B.  However, if user_type is 2 in Table A, I want to do an INNER JOIN from table C.

Much appreciated if someone could iron out the syntax in PHP :-)

Comment: While [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518526/conditional-join-statement-sql-server) is for SQL Server, I believe this should apply for MySQL as well. Edit: Or I could actually search for a [similar MySQL question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use INNER JOIN with both tables as usual, and use a CASE statement just to show table B or table C result.

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN tableA.user_type = 1 THEN tableB.user_type
                WHEN tableA.user_type = 2 THEN tableC.user_type
           END as user_type
FROM       tableA
INNER JOIN tableB 
ON         tableA.id = tableB.id
INNER JOIN tableC
ON         tableA.id = tableC.id
```

Comment: Nice answer... but should it not be `WHEN tableA.user_type = 2 THEN tableC.user_type` on the second row?

Comment: @MichaelK yep, copy&paste mistake