# Join table based on column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

**Item** table

```
id  key code    description
------------------------------
1   1   misc    miscellaneous
2   1   med     medicine
```

**Miscellaneous** table:

```
id  code    description
------------------------
1   misc1   miscellaneous
2   misc1   miscellaneous
```

**Medicine** table:

```
id  code        description
---------------------------
1   medicine1   medicine
2   medicine1   medicine
```

I have this table structure; my main table is the `Item` table and I want to JOIN the main table with other table based on the column value in main table. The column that determines the table to be joined is `code`. If code is `misc` join with `misc table` if value is `med` join with `medicine table`.

I know the basic `JOIN` of  table like

```
SELECT * 
FROM item 
INNER JOIN miscellaneous ON item.key = miscellaneous.id
```

But I don't know how to join when there is a condition that will point to which table to `JOIN`

Comment: that's real wired!!! what's that you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: be able to JOIN table based on the value of one column in main table. I have a code column which will tell on which table to JOIN like in my example if the code is misc JOIN with miscellaneous table but if code is med JOIN with medicine table @Rahul

Comment: Some options for conditional joins here [Conditional Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518526/conditional-join-statement-sql-server)

Comment: @SQLAndOtherStuffGuy will look into it and be back here ASAP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `left join`. Something like this:

```
select i.*,
       coalesce(mi.code, me.code) as code_1,
       coalesce(mi.description, me.description) as description_1
from item i left join
     miscellaneous mi
     on mi.code = i.key and i.code = 'misc' left join
     medicine me
     on me.code = i.key and i.code = 'med';
```

Comment: i didnt think this is aplicable i will give it a try and be back on here ASAP.

Comment: conditional select is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `LEFT JOIN`, that will be the easiest method to implement this.
But if you want both the table result to come under one column name, use `UNION ALL`

Using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT *
FROM item i
INNER JOIN miscellaneous m on m.code=i.code
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM item i
INNER JOIN medicine  me on me.code=i.code
```

Using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN miscellaneous m on m.code=i.code
LEFT JOIN medicine  me on me.code=i.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **Item** is your 'base' / main table, you could match other tables with LEFT JOIN so that all rows from Item tables are present.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Item AS i
LEFT JOIN Miscellaneous AS mi ON (mi.[id] = i.[key] AND i.code = 'misc')
LEFT JOIN Medicine AS me ON (me.[id] = i.[key] AND i.code = 'med');
```

You could also combine Miscellaneous & Medicine tables columns using ISNULL() function with some pre-condition

```
SELECT i.*
  , ISNULL(mi.id, me.id) AS m_id
  , ISNULL(mi.code, me.code) AS m_code
  , ISNULL(mi.description, me.description) AS m_description
FROM Item AS i
LEFT JOIN Miscellaneous AS mi ON (mi.id = i.[key] AND i.code = 'misc')
LEFT JOIN Medicine AS me ON (me.id = i.[key] AND i.code = 'med');
```

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcc8b/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a dynamic way

1. preparation of the data set for testing

   ```
   IF (OBJECT_ID('item') IS NULL)
   BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE item (id int, [key] nvarchar(128), code nvarchar(128), 
    description nvarchar(512))
    INSERT INTO item (id, [key] , code, description)
     SELECT 1, 1, 'misc', 'miscellaneous'  UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 1, 'med', 'medicine'UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 2, 'test not existing table', 'not_existing_table';
   END

   IF (OBJECT_ID('miscellaneous') IS NULL)
   BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLEe miscellaneous (id int, code nvarchar(128), description 
    nvarchar(512))
    INSERT INTO miscellaneous (id, code, description)
     SELECT 1, 'misc1', 'miscellaneous'  UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'misc2', 'miscellaneous_xxx';
   END

   IF (OBJECT_ID('medicine') IS NULL)
   BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE medicine (id int, code nvarchar(128), description 
    nvarchar(512))
    INSERT INTO medicine (id, code, description)
     SELECT 1, 'medicine1', 'medicine'  UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'medicine2', 'medicine_xxx';
   END
   ```
2. SQL Script

   ```
   DECLARE @joins nvarchar(max) ='',@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' SELECT * FROM item';


   SELECT @joins =     STUFF((SELECT ( CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '  LEFT JOIN ' + 
   description + ' ' + description + ' ON ' + description +'.id = item.[key] AND  item.description = ''' + description + '''' )
       FROM item i WHERE ISNULL(description,'') != '' AND
       (select  OBJECT_ID(description) ) IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY description
       ORDER BY description
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'');


       IF(ISNULL(@joins,'') != '' )
       BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + @joins;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
        PRINT @sql
       END;
   ```