# Add an inner or outer join based on a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, join, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is probably an easy/stupid question but is their a way to add an inner or outer join to a SQL query (with entity framework) based on data you receive?

**Example**

```
public bool method(int? typeId, int? categoryId){
    var query = from o in _dbContext.SomeObjects;

    //JOIN type
    if(typeId != null){
        //Add inner join with table types to query
        //Something like:  
        //query += join type in _dbContext.Types on o.TypeId equals type.ID
    }else{
        //Add outer join with table types to query
        //query += join type in _dbContext.Types on o.TypeId equals type.ID into types
        //             from type in types.DefaultIfEmpty()
    } 

    //Do same for category
    ...

    //Filters
    if(typeId != null){
        query += where type.ID == typeId
    }

    if(categoryId != null){
        query += where category.ID == categoryId
    }

}
```

Comment: Somewhat similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518526/conditional-join-statement-sql-server)

Comment: Somewhat but I want to know how to write it with asp ef syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing the following:

```
var query = from o in _dbContext.SomeObjects
                join type in _dbContext.Types on o.TypeId equals type.ID
            where (typeId == null || type.ID == typeId) &&
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue here is simply typing. Using `var` to store the initial query will type it as `DbSet<SomeObject>`. To build queries, you need `IQueryable<SomeObject>`. In other words, change your initial line to:

```
IQueryable<SomeObject> query = from o in _dbContext.SomeObjects;
```

I don't use LINQ-to-SQL myself, so this may be a little off, but I think then you'd just do something like:

```
query = query join type in _dbContext.Types on o.TypeId equals type.ID;
```

I know it works with LINQ-to-Entities like:

```
query = query.Include(x => x.Types);
```

Comment: That didn't worked but I fixed it with statement in my solution. Thxs for help!