# SQL conditional joins

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table-valued function with joins where I want to choose which join I use depending on a local variable like:

```
DECLARE @type int;
```

Then do some logic with @type and set it to 1.

```
SELECT ...
FROM table t
inner join ... a on a.id = t.id and @type = 1 -- Only trigger this join if @type is 1
inner join ... b on b.id = t.id and @type = 2 -- Only trigger this join if @type is 2
```

So my question is: how can I choose which join to trigger depending on the value of @type (if even possible).

The reason I want to do this is that the SELECT statement is massive, and I don't want repetitive code in the script.

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518526/conditional-join-statement-sql-server

Comment: *"how can I choose which join to trigger depending on the value of @type"* You can't, not in a function. If you want a dynamic JOIN you would need dynamic SQL, and you can't use dynamic SQL in a function. You would have to either `OUTER JOIN` to all of them and only return rows when you want them (which would expose lots of columns or you'll need a lot of `COALESCE`s) or you'll need `IF...ELSE` logic, which means a slow performance multi-line table value function.

Comment: @Larnu what about in a stored procedure?

Comment: In a Stored Procedure you could, yes, but a Stored Procedure and a Function are *very* different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could union your two tables within a subquery. For any similar columns (i.e. would be in the same column in the outer select) you can place them above each other, for columns unique to each source you'd need to pad the other side of the union with `NULL`, e.g.

```
SELECT  t.id,
        a.SimilarCol,
        a.UniqueToA,
        a.UniqueToB
FROM    Table AS t 
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT a.id, 
                    a.SimilarCol,       -- Column you would want to consider the same in each table
                    a.UniqueToA,        -- Column Unique to this table
                    UniqueToB = NULL    -- Column Unique to the other table
            FROM    SomeTable AS a 
            WHERE   @Type = 1 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  b.id, 
                    b.SimilarCol, 
                    UniqueToA = NULL, 
                    b.UniqueToB 
            FROM    SomeOtherTable AS b 
            WHERE   @type = 2
        ) AS a 
            ON a.id = t.id;
```

**[Example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c55d7790b64d5998a241fc6026c84e06)**

Comment: Note that if `@type` parameter is a constant in the outer query then this should result in an efficient query plan, with the extra join removed

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` instead:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table t LEFT JOIN
     a 
     ON a.id = t.id AND @type = 1 LEFT JOIN
     b 
     ON b.id = t.id AND @type = 2 ;
```

You might need `WHERE @type IN (1, 2)` if you want an empty result set for other values.

You will need `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT` to combine the columns:

```
COALESCE(a.col1, b.col1) as col1
```

This should be quite efficient.  However, you might want to simply use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table t JOIN
     a 
     ON a.id = t.id 
WHERE @type = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM table t JOIN
     b 
     ON b.id = t.id 
WHERE @type = 2 ;
```